# Execute code as soon as possible (before anything of third party code) in a desktop app (winforms or wpf)?

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-assembly

This is really a need because some third-party code like ***log4net*** can somehow run its code even before the ***static constructor of Program***?

I've tried embedding *log4net.dll* as resource of the project and dynamically load it when needed using event handler for `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`. However the soonest point in program I can inject here is in the static constructor of Program (to register the event handler):

```
static class Program {
     static Program(){
         AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (s,e) => {
             //...
         };
     }
}
```

But *log4net* is somehow even be involved/referenced before that point and that means it cannot be dynamically loaded, if not any raw dll found, a FileNotFoundException will be thrown.

Could you give me some suggest on what we can do in this case to run some code even before *log4net*? or generally as what I asked for, as soon as possible?

Comment: Can you reproduce this behavior in simple console application? I don't understand why you so sure it is executed before any atual logic.

Comment: @eocron I can just set some break point right in the static constructor of Program, and the exception (due to missing log4net dll) is thrown without hitting that point. I have many other dlls, but only log4net causes the issue, it  is somehow be referenced even before the point I can interfere at.

Comment: Default console application have entry point called Main, not a static constructor called Program. I ask you to ensure that this also happens in simple app, not your business model class.

Comment: I don't understand it well, but even there is not any issue in Console app, my issue is still there with GUI app.

Comment: @eocron there is only one difference I can doubt here between the 2 is the GUI app has an `app.config` file and of course to use log4net, we put some configuration into that file, that's all. The main entry points of the 2 kinds of application are much the same, they both have `Program` class which contains static Main methods.

Comment: Put your assembly code resolving before any code in Main method.

Comment: @eocron the ***static constructor of Program*** will surely be run even before anything in the Main method.

Comment: http://rextester.com/HKD15388

Comment: @eocron http://rextester.com/NNLKAU36057

Comment: Does the executable or any of its dependencies (or *their* dependencies recursively) have a reference to log4net? (Use ILDasm or Reflector to check what references are compiled in) You can use the [Fusion log viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to diagnose assembly loading.

Comment: @Richardissimo the `log4net` is used by another project which is referenced by the main project. So the sub-project is built into a dll and that is also embedded. But really if `log4net` is in need, that sub-project dll should be in need first, right? Really it's very very very hard to understand with what I know about code flow execution. All dynamic loading I've done before always allows me to debug the code right at the first curly bracket of the Program's static constructor. But here I have no chance, `FileNotFoundException` is what it throws to me in a modal popup.

Comment: I've seen a sample log from `Fusion Log Viewer` and really I don't think it can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject code even before that but not directly - VS doesn't allow that on it's own. You have to do it on IL level (by hand modifying IL code) or use some 3rd party tools that can do this - like [Fody ModuleInit](https://github.com/Fody/ModuleInit) weaver.

What it does it will inject your code into the Module's code - the one that's visible in disassemblers as `<Module>`. This code will be executed when your module is loaded so it will be before static ctor.

Having such code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
  class Program
  {
      static Program()
      {
          Console.WriteLine("static ctor of Program");
      }
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Main");
      }
  }

  public static class ModuleInitializer
  {
      public static void Initialize()
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Module Initializer");
      }
  }
}
```

and `Fody` & `Module Init` as `nuget` packages installed will yield

[image]

Additionally, Fody has a module that does that what it looks like you need - [Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura/) can pack all external dependencies into resources.

Comment: Thank you this is a nice approach, the disadvantage here is we need to use a custom lib to inject IL somehow. Actually I remembered that we have some way to pre-execute some code before anything in the app but I forgot that and really hope this question could be answered easily by someone advanced in this field. I would give this answer an up-vote and wait for another better answer later (by opening bounty). If at last there is not any better, I will accept this answer. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes, that's true but you could do this by hand ;) (changing the generated IL - not recommended) or write the same what fody does - using Cecil. The plus of Fody is that it removes itself almost completely from the generated assembly and there is no need to include it as a reference in order to your application to work.